# How do I log in to a site with a double request?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, authorization

I'm trying to log in to the site, but I have a problem!
Here is my code:

```
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
import requests
from main import username, password


data = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Authorization": "NTLM TlRMTVNT.......",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cookie": "_ym_uid=1654686701790358885; _ym_d=1654686701; _ym_isad=2",
    "Host": "...",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Referer": "https://...",
    "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="104", "Opera GX";v="90"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
              "Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/90.0.4480.117"
}

auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)

with requests.Session() as session:
    q1 = session.get("https://...", auth=auth, headers=data)
    data['Authorization'] = q1.headers.get("WWW-Authenticate")
    q2 = session.get("https://...", auth=auth, headers=data)
    print(q2.raise_for_status())
```

You need to log in inside the site. I used to use HttpBaseAuth, but after searching in the site files I saw that it does a strange thing using NTLM.
He makes a get request using my headers, receives a 401 and another "WWW-Authenticate" header in the response and resends this request, but with the changed "Authorization" header just the same to the value of the "WWW-Authenticate" header. The header "Authorization" in the very first request is always the same, the values do not change (unfortunately I can't write it here), but if you send it yourself, then the response is still 401 and via response.headers.get not view
What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP3bV.png)

I can't log in to the site.
If you log in manually, in the browser, it makes a get request, receives the “WWW-authenticate” header in response, and makes a get request again, but with this header.
When I try to do the same thing through python, I get a 401 error.

Comment: What is the error/issue you're facing? Does the code run into any errors?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\LoadWebsite\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(q2.raise_for_status())
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\LoadWebsite\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://mydoc.spbgasu.ru/18000052/

Comment: No types of authorization help to enter the site

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.